# Receiving unread or new posts from forums with slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am a beginner in Slack.
I want to make a slack-bot that fetches unread or new posts from forums.

For examples,
If there are any posts I have not read in specific forums, Slack-bot will let me know.

So what slack api should I use? Or what documentation should I read?

Comment: Isn't that what notifications are for?

Comment: Hi jrenk, for example this link. https://python-forum.io/Forum-Homework

Comment: In the link, there are posts. I want to track them.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to add an [RSS Feed integration](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/218688467-Add-RSS-feeds-to-Slack) to your Slack workspace, and then configure it to subscribe to the Python Forum you linked in your comment.

After adding the RSS feed integration to Slack, click the [RSS Syndication link](https://python-forum.io/misc.php?action=syndication) in the Python Forum's footer to generate an update feed link and then paste it into the Slack RSS Feed integration settings.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try your suggestion.